# Inner join 2 tabelas and get last result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble writing the query that returns the last id by date of a table and fetching the name of that id from another table

```
SELECT l1.* 
FROM ficha_eventos l1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT l2.`SQ_FICHA`, MAX(l2.`id`) as maxid 
            FROM ficha_eventos l2 
            GROUP BY l2.`SQ_FICHA`
           ) l3 ON l3.maxid = l1.id
```

**Result above**

```
2| 1 |2014-04-04 | ok
6| 2 |2014-04-04 | ok
4| 3 |2014-04-04 | ok
```

```
ficha_cadastro

SQ_FICHA|NOME|

1|gabriel
2|carlos
3|manuel

ficha_evento

id|dia_atendimento|ligacao_atendimento|SQ_FICHA

1 | 2011-01-01 | no | 1
2 | 2014-04-04 | ok | 1
3 | 2012-01-01 | no | 2
4 | 2013-03-03 | ok | 3
5 | 2013-01-01 | no | 3
6 | 2014-04-04 | ok | 2
```

**Result I want**

```
2|gabriel|2014-04-04 | ok
6|carlos|2014-04-04 | ok
4|manuel|2014-04-04 | ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mysql 5.x you can use inner joins to acheive what you want.

but  manuel has not the result you has shown us, it must be 2013-03-03 instead

the joins can be If you have more elements than events and still want to see them you must use RIGHT JOIN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ficha_cadastro (
>   `SQ_FICHA` INTEGER,
>   `NOME` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ficha_cadastro
>   (`SQ_FICHA`, `NOME`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'gabriel'),
>   ('2', 'carlos'),
>   ('3', 'manuel');
>
> CREATE TABLE ficha_evento (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `dia_atendimento` Date,
>   `ligacao_atendimento` VARCHAR(2),
>   `SQ_FICHA` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ficha_evento
>   (`id`, `dia_atendimento`, `ligacao_atendimento`, `SQ_FICHA`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2011-01-01', 'no', '1'),
>   ('2', '2014-04-04', 'ok', '1'),
>   ('3', '2012-01-01', 'no', '2'),
>   ('4', '2013-03-03', 'ok', '3'),
>   ('5', '2013-01-01', 'no', '3'),
>   ('6', '2014-04-04', 'ok', '2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     f.id, f.dia_atendimento, fa.NOME, f.ligacao_atendimento
> FROM
>     ficha_evento f
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         MAX(dia_atendimento) daxdate, SQ_FICHA
>     FROM
>         ficha_evento
>     GROUP BY SQ_FICHA) f1 ON f1.daxdate = f.`dia_atendimento`
>         AND f1.SQ_FICHA = f.SQ_FICHA
>         INNER JOIN
>     ficha_cadastro fa ON fa.SQ_FICHA = f.SQ_FICHA
> ORDER BY f.SQ_FICHA
> ```
>
> ```
> id | dia_atendimento | NOME    | ligacao_atendimento
> -: | :-------------- | :------ | :------------------
>  2 | 2014-04-04      | gabriel | ok                 
>  6 | 2014-04-04      | carlos  | ok                 
>  4 | 2013-03-03      | manuel  | ok
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0145a96dffb2e6b953551ee85fc7e38)*

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify the rows you want. For example:

```
select
  e.id,
  c.nome,
  e.dia_atendimento,
  e.ligacao_atendimento,
  row_number() over(partition by e.sql_ficha 
                    order by e.dia_atendimento desc) as rn
from ficha_evento e
join ficha_cadastro c on c.sq_ficha = e.sq_ficha
where rn = 1
```

Comment: `SELECT l1.* FROM ficha_eventos l1 INNER JOIN (SELECT l2.`SQ_FICHA`, MAX(l2.`id`) as maxid FROM ficha_eventos l2 GROUP BY l2.`SQ_FICHA` ) l3 ON l3.maxid = l1.id `

Comment: I managed to do it this way, now I can't bring the user's name from another table